# how to remove write protection in memory card?

Tags: usb-storage, memory-card

I have a 4 gb micro sd card ,now my memory card is not properly working and when i insert card into phone it shows card is write protected..
it even not recognised in system give me a helpful solution to recover my memory card..

Comment: Have you recently plugged it into a PC? Is that an option to test it to verify it works fine?

Comment: I’ve read that some card-readers are a little flaky, so you have to set the write-protect switch to the *middle* to get it to not think it is write-protected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a MicroSD to SD adapter(something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GGL7Z4))????

If yes, note that there is a switch on the upper left side. It locks the SD to read-only state. Check it and change the switch and then you can write files/photos on it again.

Comment: I've done that several times putting an SD card in my camera. Problem solved with a small drop of super glue!